# JOptionPane.showInputDialog: what is the best way to check that the Cancel or X was clicked?

Tags: java, swing

I just started learning Java, and I'm wondering if I chose the correct way of checking if the user clicked Cancel or X on JOptionPane.showInputDialog? Please see the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    private static double a;
    private static double b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        requestA();
    }
    private static void requestA() {
        String aString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a");
        try {
            a = Double.parseDouble(aString);
            requestB();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input a number!");
            requestA();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    private static void requestB() {
        String bString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input b");
        try {
            b = Double.parseDouble(bString);
            showResult();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input a number!");
            requestB();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    private static void showResult() {
        double x = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x);
        requestA();
    }
}
```

And generally speaking, if you have any recommendations on how to organize the above code better, please share.

Thank you in advance!

The above code is working, I'm asking if there is a better way to achieve the same.